# Проверка на страницу в WordPress

Tags: php, веб-программирование, wordpress

Здравствуйте, недавно понадобилось сделать так, чтобы на разных страницах выводилось разное содержание.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы на разных страницах, было разное содержание, то есть, чтобы, например, на странице "Обо мне" выводился определенный блок, а на странице "Контакты" нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, конечно, есть функция [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). Однако, вынжден предупредить, что используя ее, вы открываете ящик пандоры, т.к. прямое указание названия / ID захардкодит его в теме, а вам, скорее всего, нужно иметь управление этим ID через админку. Для этого стоит использовать механизм опций и сохранять это значение в опцию.